# Simulated annealing cost function for TSP

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, traveling-salesman, simulated-annealing

How does the cost function work for the TSP? Say I have a tour which has a distance of 100, and I change the tour slightly, making 4 changes to the original and it now has a distance of 50.

Would the cost function give me 4, because that's the number of changes; or 50, because of the change in distance? Or maybe I'm missing something and it's neither?

Comment: Er, neither - it would be 50, but because that's the distance, not because it's the change.  You only care about the solution, not the steps you took to find it.

Comment: Ohh sorry, so would the energy be 50 as well because that's how much the distance has changed?

Answer (score 1):

The cost function is the **total distance**.

It is exactly what you want to be minimal.

Comment: Ohh sorry, so would the energy be 50 as well because that's how much the distance has changed?

Comment: No. Because that's how much the salesman will walk on his tour.

Comment: So what would the energy be? I thought it was the change in cost?

Answer (score 1):

The cost function *is* the total distance, yes, but it is *also* the energy parameter $E$ in Simulated Annealing.  It is not the "energy" $E$ that directly determines the probability of transitioning to that state, but it is rather `$\Delta{E}$`, the change in energy (the change in cost), that determines the probability `$P(\Delta{E})=exp(-\Delta{E}/T)$`.

So the transition from $E=100$ to $E=50$ would be `$\Delta{E}=-50$` (100% probability).

The transition from $E=100$ to $E=150$ would be $\Delta{E}=50$, and a probability of ~0.7% if the temperature were 10. `$P(\Delta{E}=50)=e^{-50/10}$`.